# Android:Dynamically resize the graphic object according to the screen layout

Tags: android, graphics, screen-orientation

Is it possible to change the graphic object according to the orientation of the screen.
Say for e.g. I draw a wide rectangle in landscape mode , but if i go to the portrait mode i can see only half of the rectangle drawn.

Is it programatically possible to resize according to the orientation of the screen ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the manifest file and write required drawing code in  `onConfigurationChange()` in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Display object in your custom view to get current width/height of screen, 
e.g. **`display.getWidth()`** and **`display.getHeight()`**.

You can obtain display object in activity as follows:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
```